# 133 error while connecting to BLE devices on some Android Device (Samsung)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, connectivity

I am developing application with a BLE device "Puck Js". I required to connect to this device using a android application on some of devices.

One Some of the devices we are able to connect and all the things are working fine. But on some devices specially Samsung and some other custom os versions.We are some issues in pairing the device.

While connecting to the device we get 133 error and connection is not made sometime device get paired but later it get disconnected and not able to reconnect to device.

One more issue we are getting. In one device we are not able to detect the services running on the puck device. Which we have installed using the custom js script i have also asked earlier. (After restarting the (Android)device it start detecting).

Please help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: hi i am facing the same issue did you found any solution. I am getting the 133 error on Samsung  devices in android